# What is the equivalent to NetServices in ActionScript 3

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript-1

I'm working on updating a legacy system from ActionScript to ActionScript 3. Does anyone here know what the equivalent to NetServices in ActionScript 3 is? I'm looking for a class that has a setDefaultGatewayURL. I've tried googling but I haven't run into much luck (primarily because there ain't that many AS services online anymore). Thanks.

Comment: To kind of answer my own question, would it be fair to say that mx.rpc.HTTPService implements many of the methods from NetServices? Thanks.

Comment: We don't deal with much AS1 on here, and I personally have never used it before. Could you either provide the documentation from Adobe/Macromedia for `NetServices` or describe what exactly it is you need the class to do? The main method of network communication in AS3 is `URLLoader`/`URLStream`, but there are a few other ways to do it.